# Rename record dn in LDAP with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, openldap

I need help with Java SpringBoot LdapRepository. I have a model with @Entry annotation with objectClass and base. Now I need to move this record to another branch. Is it possible with LdapRepository or I need to create new model with another DN and save record using another model? I don't implement interface, so it could be a little problem. When I just change id (javax.Naming) of record I gane NamingException and it isn't working. I tried to find a solution, but I have never found any example with change branch of record.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Best regards,
Patrick

PS. Model:

```
@Entry(
        base = "my dn",
        objectClasses = {
                /*some object classes */
        }
)
@Getter
@Setter
public final class WiFiGuestLDAP {
    @Id
    private Name id;
    private String cn;
    /*some attributes*/
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface WiFiGuestRepositoryLDAP extends LdapRepository<WiFiGuestLDAP> {
    @Cacheable
    Iterable<WiFiGuestLDAP> findAll();

    List<WiFiGuestLDAP> findByVALUEIgnoreCase(String VALUE);
}
```